# shell script not executing

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to run a shell script on unix, but I am getting an error specifying it can't be executed.

**Command**

```
Unix> Abc.ksh
ksh: Abc.ksh: cannot execute
```

Also tried

```
pcasvs17 >  ./Abc.ksh
ksh: ./Abc.ksh: cannot execute
```

The script starts with

```
 #!/bin/ksh
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chmod +x Abc.ksh` and try again with `./Abc.ksh`

Comment: Thanks Mate , it worked. I'll accept the anwer.The access available before was `-rw-r--r--` , after running the command the access available was `-rwxr-xr--`

Comment: Can you explain why we need to do that?

Comment: the x means "executable".  Before the chmod command, the file could be Read and Written, but not eXecuted (not even by the person who wrote it)